# 1 Downvote + 1 upvote = 1 upvote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I post an answer to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65711/how-can-i-change-the-shortcut-keys-for-my-macbook-pro-so-it-doesnt-conflict-wit/66897#66897).

My answer receives a downvote (also if I don't understand why) and 1 upvote. As a result a earned 9 points. That's ok.

However when I look at the answer it has 1 point. How can it be possible, shouldn't it be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if there was a downvote, it has been uncast, so that there is no downvote on the question now:

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the green +1 and the red 0. Probably I don't have enough reputation. What is an uncasted downvote? Now indeed I had the 1 point back. Thanks!

Comment: It means someone voted against your post, then changed their mind and reversed their vote.

Comment: And indeed, you need 1000 reputation points to see the number of up and down votes on a post, rather than their sum.